# Account verification email is not working after 25 signup

Tags: nodemailer

We are facing a problem with account verification emails. we are getting 550 error code if more than 25 users signup on our website within 24 hours.

We are using node-mailer and our website is hosted on AWS. The email hosting provider is GoDaddy. I spoke with the GoDaddy team and they said this problem is not from their side as I am able to send more than 25 emails from webmail.

Error Message:

error sending email error: Mail command failed: 550 User xxx@xxx.com has exceeded its 24-hours sending limit. Message to 25 recipients out of 25 allowed have been sent. Relay quota will reset in 22.01 hours

Comment: I'm also getting this error. is this resloved ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Kindly try using this node JS package, you can add in your custom Business Email Ids, so that you can support over 200+ mails in a day, it also has a default Mail Id that can handle 100+ mails in a day, if you need so, you can go with custom mail Ids also

Kindly use the NPM Package **(two-step-auth)**

This will take care of the whole verification process, you don't need to worry about the backend work :), This will give you an OTP and you can work with it

For custom mail ID usage kindly check the github repo

[Kindly check the full procedures with example here](https://github.com/saran-surya/two-step-auth)

### Usage

```js
const {Auth} = require('two-step-auth');

async function login(emailId){
    const res = await Auth(emailId);
    // You can follw the above approach, But we recommend you to follow the one below, as the mails will be treated as important
    const res = await Auth(emailId, "Company Name");
    console.log(res);
    console.log(res.mail);
    console.log(res.OTP);
    console.log(res.success);
}

login("YourEmail@anyDomain.com")
```

### Output

[image]
This will help you a lot taking care of the process of verification under the HOOD :)